# Chinese characters garbled

Tags: xcode, excel, csv

I wrote a servlet to download database records that include chinese characters. The download file is in csv format. The servlet response content type is set to
"text/csv; charset=utf-8".

when I open the csv in Excel, the Chinese chars are unreadable. But, if I open the same file using xcode editor, they show up fine.

I am not able to find any setting for char encoding in either application.

what can be the difference between Excel and Xcode editor?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a limitation of Excel's handling of CSV files. You can try tab separated format with `txt` extension:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"(nǐ hǎo) - inf"  : @"你好",
                             @"(hǎojǐu bújiàn)" : @"好久不見 [好久不见]"};

NSString *documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *path          = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];

NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString string];

for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    [string appendString:key];
    [string appendString:@"\t"];
    [string appendString:dictionary[key]];
    [string appendString:@"\n"];
}

NSError *error;
BOOL success = [string writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding error:&error];
NSAssert(success, @"error = %@", error);
```

I was able to open this file in Excel. But I had to use `NSUTF16StringEncoding`, not `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.